# How to change the theme of streamlit?

Tags: python, themes, streamlit

I'm having trouble changing the theme of my webapp. I'm using the Visual Studio Code program to program and there, I opened a folder named `.streamlit` and inside it, a file named `config.toml`. I pasted the theme changes, but when I refreshed the page, they were not saved. What could have happened?

My theme:

```
[theme]
base="dark"
primaryColor="#fff700"
```

Print of Visual code:
[image: visualcode]

Comment: What is your operating system type?

Answer (score 0):

Check on the `Menu > Settings > Theme`:

[image: Custom Theme]

There is a list of themes you can choose from:

[image: Drop down]

Choose the "Custom Theme" from it.

Comment: I tried it, but when I refresh the page the settings go back to default

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the theme flags when running streamlit from the command line. For example:

```
streamlit run webapp.py --theme.primaryColor="FFF700" --theme.base="dark"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your app after making the changes to the `.streamli/config.toml` file.

Kill the terminal and launch the app again:
`streamlit run NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE`